# How to get several data from a form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

I have two added form. In the first, I choose one client and for him I add several domains names.
Then, when I clik to next, I arrived on a second form in which there are the several domains names (I added before ) in each row with others fields for each one (registar, url and remark). It seems to like this :

> toto.com    | Directnic |   www.toto.com | blablabla 
>   toto.fr   | Afnic |   www.toto.fr | bla 
>   toto.net   | Gandi |   www.toto.net | blabla

But when I want to recover this data into my action to add them into my database, I get only the last line. Why ?

My form :

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('@add_domaines');?>" method="post">

    <?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors() ?>

    <table class="form_add_domaines">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo $form['nom_domaine']->renderLabel()?></th>
                <th><?php echo $form['compte_registar_id']->renderLabel() ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $form['url']->renderLabel() ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $form['remarque']->renderLabel() ?></th>
            </tr>   
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php 
            $domaines = explode("\n",$add_domaines);
            for($i=0; $i<count($domaines); $i++)
            {?> 
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php 
                        if(1==strcmp(' ', $domaines[$i]))
                        {
                            echo "<span style='color:red;'>"."<b>Warning, missing domain name.</b>"."</span>";
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            echo $domaines[$i];
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <?php echo $form['compte_registar_id']->renderError() ?>

                        <?php echo $form['compte_registar_id'] ?>
                    </td>


                    <td>

                        <?php echo $form['url']->renderError() ?>

                        <?php echo $form['url'] ?>
                    </td>

                    <td>

                        <?php echo $form['remarque']->renderError() ?>

                        <?php echo $form['remarque'] ?>
                    </td>           
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>          
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo link_to(__('Back', array(), 'sf_admin'), '@domaine_new') ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(false) ?>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</form>
```

My action :

```
[...]    
$this->form = new AddDomainesForm();

$this->form->setDefault('client_id', $idClient);
$this->form->setDefault('nom_domaine', $noms_domaine);

if($request->isMethod('post'))
            {

                $name = $this->form->getName();

                $values = $request->getParameter($name);
                $files = $request->getFiles($name);

                $this->form->bind($values, $files);

                if($this->form->isValid())
                {
                    print_r($values);break;
                    //$this->form->save();

                    $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', 'OK.');
                    $this->redirect('@domaine');
                }
            }
```

`print_r($values)` return only the last row of my form

> Array ( [compte_registar_id] => 1 [url] => www.toto.net [remarque] => blabla  [nom_domaine] => toto.com toto.fr toto.net [client_id] => 17 [_csrf_token] => ... )

Thank you !

Comment: gimme the form HTML, plz

Comment: I added, look up please :)

Comment: I think you have to embed the `AddDomainesForm` into an another one (e.g. sfFrom). It is explained [here](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) in the docs how to do that.

Comment: I have read the docs but it is not my case because in my case I have only one form which is repeat several time... Anybody else ?

Comment: I resolved my problem using a loop in my form class passing $i to the widget name :)

Answer (score 0):

When multiple form elements have the same name, only the last one will be taken.

Did you see that cou can send arrays directly?

```
<inut type="text" name="foobarlist[]">
<inut type="text" name="foobarlist[]">
<inut type="text" name="foobarlist[]">
```

$_GET['foobarlist'] will return an array with 3 elements.

The brackets are the key.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I did not know :)